# Why can I get an image from public folder but not a json file

Tags: reactjs

I learn Reactjs and came across this

I have an images folder in the public React project created with create-react-app.
I place a json file and a jpg in it and I can use the jpg but not the json.

```
 let photo = "./images/some.jpg";
 let file  = "./images/somejson.json";
```

The image works out of the box like

```
<img alt="image" src={photo} />
```

But the json cant be read I get `Cannot read property 'label' of undefined`

```
<h1 className="title">{file.basics.label}</h1>
```

And this is the json

```
{
  "basics": {
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "label": "Some label"
  }
}
```

Please advice what is wrong?

Comment: Can you try logging the type of `file` : `console.log(typeof file)`?

Comment: I get string not undefined

Comment: Are you using it as string or import it `import json from "./images/somejson.json"`?

Answer (score 2):

You should import JSON file before use its properties, your `file` variable is just a path to a JSON file. If you are using `create-react-app` it has `json-loader`, if not you have to install it and configure your `Webpack`, I can assume you already use it, and then you can import JSON file and use it.

```
import json from "./images/somejson.json"

...

<img src={json.someSrc} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace `.json` from `public` to `src` folder. And also you should export your variable `file` in the `somejson.json` file. and also you should import this variable too.

Comment: I don't want to do that since the json must be publicly acceptable for changes in the public folder. I want to remotely control the app meta data using the json

Comment: is there a variable in your json file that u can export it?Or u dont want to use variable? i didnt undertand this part.

Comment: I have the .json file in the `src` folder now and it's working but I must move it to the public folder so I can upload changes to the json

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file, import your json file with correct path.

```
import file from './somejson.json';
```

If you need to retain this file in public/ and also use it in React app, add this library.
https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias

```
import file from '../public/images/somejson.json';
```

Comment: I don't want to do that since the json must be publicly acceptable for changes in the public folder. I want to remotely control the app meta data using the json

Comment: got you. refer to react-app-rewire. create-react-app doesn't allow using files other than /src. this will help in overcoming the limitation and you can use the file from public/ in your app.

Comment: But how can I use the image in public folder but not the json?